# Integral of f*g = f(c) times integral of g?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

For two continuous functions, $f,g:[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $g(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, I want to show there exists a $c\in[a,b]$ such that:

$\int_a^b f.g=f(c)\int_a^b g$

I've thought about using the intermediate value theorem (since I'm trying to show existence of a point in [a,b], but I've had no luck with that and wondering if I'm going the wrong way about it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $u\le f(x)\le v$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then $g\ge0$ implies $$\int_a^bug(x)\,\mathrm dx \le \int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx\le \int_a^bvg(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$